# Understanding the Basics of Markdown and Knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-visualization, knitr

I am using the R programming language. Recently, I came across the following website which shows how to make professional style data visualizations using R (https://www.cedricscherer.com/2021/01/01/review-2020-personal-dataviz-highlights/). This website links to the author's github page which allows you to download a zip folder containing the entire repositories of code required for these data visualizations (https://github.com/Z3tt/30DayMapChallenge) :

[image]

This folder contains many "RMD" files for the R codes required to make these visualizations (TidyTuesday-master -> R)

[image]

If you "double click" on one of these files (e.g. "2020_14_BeerProduction.Rmd"), it will automatically open in R studio, with the code appearing in the R markdown editor window. From there, I clicked on "Knit -> Knit to HTML")

I ran the following code in the editor window (knit -> knit to html):

````
---
title: "TidyTuesday 2020/14 - The Office Ratings by IMDb & data.world"
author: "Cedric Scherer"
date: "3rd of April 2020"
output:
  html_document:
  theme: paper
highlight: kate
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = F)
```

```{r prep, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
## packages
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)

font_add_google("Roboto Mono", "Roboto Mono")
font_add_google("Open Sans", "Open Sans")
font_add_google("Bangers", "Bangers")

## ggplot theme
theme_set(theme_minimal(base_family = "Bangers"))

theme_update(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#3c2554", color = "#3c2554"),
             panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
             panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
             panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
             panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
             axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, color = "#e0d796", margin = margin(t = 10)),
             axis.text.y = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks = element_blank(),
             plot.margin = margin(0, 30, 30, 30))
```

```{r data}
df_brewers <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-31/brewer_size.csv')
```

```{r data-prep}
df_brew <- 
  df_brewers %>% 
  filter(
    #!brewer_size %in% c("Total", "Zero Barrels", "6,000,001 Barrels and Over")
    brewer_size %in% c("Under 1 Barrel", "1 to 1,000 Barrels")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(year_mod = year + (year %% min(year, na.rm = T) + 1)) %>% 
  group_by(year, year_mod) %>% 
  summarize(
    n_of_brewers = sum(n_of_brewers, na.rm = T),
    total = sum(total_barrels, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(label = glue::glue("{format(round(total / 10^6, 2), nsmall = 2)}M"))

df_ticks <-
  df_brew %>% 
  slice(rep(1, each = 5)) %>% 
  mutate(
    tick = seq(0.25*10^6, 1.25*10^6, by = 2.5*10^5),
    label = c("0.25", "0.50", "0.75", "1.00", "1.25")
  ) %>% 
  filter(tick < total - 50000)
  
set.seed(2)

df_brewers <-
  df_brew %>% 
  slice(rep(1, each = floor(n_of_brewers / 100))) %>% 
  mutate(
    dots_brewer = runif(n_of_brewers, 20000, total - 20000),
    dot_size = runif(n_of_brewers, 0, 1)
  )
```


```{r plot, fig.width = 24, fig.height = 11}
df_brew %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year_mod, total)) +
    geom_segment(data = df_brew %>% slice(1),
                 aes(x = year_mod - .6, 
                      xend = year_mod + .6,
                      yend = total),
                 color = "white",
                 size = 35) +
    geom_col(fill = "#f9e556", width = 1.2) +
    ## bubbles
    geom_jitter(data = df_brewers,
                aes(year_mod, dots_brewer,
                    size = dot_size),
                position = position_jitter(width = .38, seed = 1),
                shape = 21,
                color = colorspace::darken("#f9e556", .17),
                stroke = .5) +
    ## scale bar
    geom_segment(data = df_brew,
                 aes(x = year_mod + .676,
                     xend = year_mod + .676,
                     y = 0,
                     yend = total),
                 color = "white",
                 size = 1.5) +
    # total label
    geom_segment(data = df_brew,
                 aes(x = year_mod + .655,
                     xend = year_mod + .77,
                     y = total - 3500,  ## total only: - 2500
                     yend = total - 3500),  ## total only: - 2500
                 color = "white",
                 size = 1.5) +  ## total only: .7
    geom_text(aes(year_mod + .83, 
                  total - 3500,  ## total only: - 2500
                  label = label),
              family = "Roboto Mono",
              fontface = "bold",
              color = "white",
              size = 4,
              hjust = 0) +
    ## null label
    geom_segment(data = df_brew,
                 aes(x = year_mod + .655,
                     xend = year_mod + .77,
                     y = 3500,
                     yend = 3500),
                 color = "white",
                 size = 1.5) +
    geom_text(aes(year_mod + .83, 
                  3500,
                  label = "0.00"),
              family = "Roboto Mono",
              fontface = "bold",
              color = "white",
              size = 4,
              hjust = 0) +
    ## other ticks
    geom_segment(data = df_ticks,
                 aes(x = year_mod + .675,
                     xend = year_mod + .78,
                     y = tick,
                     yend = tick),
                 color = "white",
                 size = .8) +
    # geom_text(data = df_ticks,
    #           aes(year_mod + .86,
    #               tick,
    #               label = label),
    #           family = "Roboto Mono",
    #           fontface = "bold",
    #           color = "grey80",
    #           size = 4,
    #           hjust = 0) +
    ## title
    annotate("text", x = 2017, y = 1.5*10^6, 
             label = "The Rise of Craft Beer !",
             family = "Bangers",
             color = "#f9e556",
             size = 40,
             hjust = .5) +
    ## subtitle
    annotate("text", x = 2017, y = 1.27*10^6, 
             label = "Beer production of small US breweries with brewer sizes below 1,000 barrels increased by 225%\nover the last ten years. In the same time also the number of brewers increased by around 290%.",
             family = "Open Sans",
             fontface = "bold",
             lineheight = .99,
             color = "#e0d796",
             size = 6,
             hjust = .5) +
    annotate("text", x = 2017, y = 1.18*10^6, 
             label = "The yellow bars show the number of total barrels of beer produced by year and each bubble represents 100 brewers.",
             family = "Open Sans",
             color = "#e0d796",
             size = 5,
             hjust = .5) +
    ## caption
    annotate("text", x = 2017, y = 1.05*10^6, 
             label = "Visualization by Cédric Scherer  •  Data from the Alcohol and Tobacco Tax and Trade Bureau (TTB)",
             family = "Bangers",
             #fontface = "bold",
             color = "#703da4",
             size = 6.7,
             hjust = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.005, .005),
                       limits = c(NA, max(df_brew$year_mod) + 1.2),
                       breaks = seq(min(df_brew$year_mod), max(df_brew$year_mod), by = 2),
                       labels = c(min(df_brew$year):max(df_brew$year))) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.005, .005),
                       limits = c(0, 1750000)) +
                       #labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = ",")) +
    scale_size(range = c(2, 5), guide = F) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)


ggsave(here::here("plots", "2020_14", "2020_14_BeerProduction.pdf"),
       width = 24, height = 11, device = cairo_pdf)

pdftools::pdf_convert(here::here("plots", "2020_14", "2020_14_BeerProduction.pdf"),
                      format = "png", dpi = 350)
```

***

```{r session-info}
sessionInfo()
```
````

[image]

But this produces the following error:

[image]

I am not sure what this error is referring to. I tried searching online for what "cairo_pdf" might be about, but I couldn't find anything. I installed an R package called "cairo", but this did not solve the problem. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: Session Info

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pdftools_2.3.1    systemfonts_1.0.1 ggtext_0.1.1      forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.3      
 [7] purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.2       tibble_3.0.5      ggplot2_3.3.3     tidyverse_1.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lubridate_1.7.9.2 here_1.0.1        assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2   digest_0.6.27    
 [7] R6_2.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.2.1   reprex_1.0.0      evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.2       
[13] pillar_1.4.7      rlang_0.4.10      curl_4.3          readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13   rmarkdown_2.7    
[19] qpdf_1.1          RCurl_1.98-1.3    munsell_0.5.0     gridtext_0.1.4    tinytex_0.30      broom_0.7.5      
[25] compiler_4.0.3    modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.21         pkgconfig_2.0.3   askpass_1.1       htmltools_0.5.1.1
[31] tidyselect_1.1.0  fansi_0.4.2       crayon_1.3.4      dbplyr_2.1.0      withr_2.4.1       bitops_1.0-6     
[37] grid_4.0.3        jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.0   DBI_1.1.1         git2r_0.28.0     
[43] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      cli_2.2.0         stringi_1.5.3     farver_2.0.3      fs_1.5.0         
[49] xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1    generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6       tools_4.0.3       glue_1.4.2       
[55] markdown_1.1      hms_1.0.0         jpeg_0.1-8.1      yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_2.0-0  rvest_1.0.0      
[61] knitr_1.31        haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: What version of R are you running? What happens if you remove the `device = cairo_pdf` part from the call to `ggsave()` in the markdown document?

Comment: I am using R version 4.0.3 (I just made an edit, and posted the session information in the original question)

Comment: Just a question - is the R code supposed to go into the R markdown window, or is this suppose to go into the R console? Are you supposed to click "knit to html" afterwards?

Comment: it also returns "TURE" on my windows machine as well

Comment: I just copy and pasted this entire code into R console and it (somewhat) worked! Although lots of warnings, a few errors and some of the text is cut off

Comment: @MrFlick Ugh, confused Cairo with Quartz. Never mind. I’m now actually surprised the author fo these nice-looking plots is using Cairo … in my experience its text rendering is very buggy and *definitely* not suitable for professional plots. Maybe they have improved.

Comment: I think: "Error: unable to start device cairo_pdf when knitting RMarkdown" (or similar) would be a more descriptive title for your question.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `opts_chunk$set(dev='cairo_pdf')`. BTW the `cairo_pdf` device is part of the default package grDevices.